# Strange Date behavior in Chrome

Tags: javascript, datetime

Why these nearly similar date objects give different results in Chrome 37?

```
var d2014 = new Date(2014, 0, 1);
alert(d2014.getFullYear()); // 2013

var d2015 = new Date(2015, 0, 1);
alert(d2015.getFullYear()); // 2015
```

In IE11 I get "2014" and "2015" as expected. Browser works in Russian locale. Conversion to strings gives the following results:

```
d2014.toString();    // Tue Dec 31 2013 23:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
d2015.toString();    // Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))

d2014.toUTCString(); // Tue, 31 Dec 2013 20:00:00 GMT
d2015.toUTCString(); // Wed, 31 Dec 2014 21:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: I'm getting "2014" and "2015" (Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 m)

Comment: also, you can just use strings: `new Date("2014");`.. See example: **http://jsfiddle.net/ydjc9g1f/3/**

Comment: same problem with new Date("2014") - http://impresite.ru/uploads/chrome.png Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m

Comment: What if you try other dates and times in 2014? Can you identify the exact time that the one hour discrepancy appears?

Comment: I've tested years from 2000 to 2030 and got wrong results on: 2003, 2014, 2020, 2025.

Comment: @BorisMitchenko - in your picture 2014 still uses `new Date(2014, 0, 1);`, only 2015 uses string.. Did you try `new Date("2014")`?

Comment: new Date("2014") works correct, but it is UTC. In local time I get 2014-01-01 04:00 but I need 2014-01-01 00:00 in local time.

Comment: you could maybe use `getTimezoneOffset` [**(link)**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp), and substract/add the offset hours

Comment: getTimezoneOffset doesn't work. new Date(2014, 0, 1) is "Tue, 31 Dec 2013 20:00:00 GMT" in UTC. But getTimezoneOffset is only -180 (expected -240).

Comment: There is a bug report on Chromium issue tracker - opened 25. September. With some discussion going on: [Chromium - Issuses](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417640)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a chrome specific issue, you can view the discussion here https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3116 and in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417640 look for
 `#31 ulan@chromium.org`,

This issue is fixed in version 3.29.39